# How to reference a module property in tibco-bw6 from XPath

Tags: xpath, tibco, tibco-business-works

I'm trying to reference a module property from *tibco business works 6*.

Do you guys have an example about the `getModuleProperty("")`?
What kind of input should I use?
Should I use the entire path or just the name of the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to include a few dependencies in your project. ([Documented here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.4.0/doc/html/GUID-0789354B-8A60-4E70-B492-5E155FE18D6F.html))

Then write some code access the properties

```
    @ModuleProperties
public void loadProperties(HashMap<String, String> moduleProperties){
    this.myClassProperty = moduleProperties.get("/DB/Property"); // Case Sensitive Path
    System.out.println("Completed loading module properties.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first add a process property to your process (it's under properties if you click outside of the main process area). In there you can reference a module property. You can then use the process property in XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the entire path of the property. you can get it from the `META-INF/default.substvar` file.